# Populate jtable from multiple MS Access databases

Tags: java, ms-access, jtable, multiple-databases

I successfully managed to populate jtable from an MS Access database using UcanAccess library.

What I want is to populate jtable from two databases. I have two databases, one contains table with four columns, the other contain three columns.
I want to populate jtable with seven columns from the two databases.

Code used :

```
public void PopulateJtable(JTable table, String table_name) {
    String sql = "SELECT * from " + table_name;
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDB);
        state = conn.createStatement();
        state.execute(sql);
        ResultSet rs = state.getResultSet();
        int columns = table.getColumnCount();
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector row = new Vector();

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            dtm.addRow(row);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR !! ", 0);
    } finally {
        try {
            state.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

MS Access DB Tables :
[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtB9k.png)

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DuR3.png)

i want to join above tables cols in one jtable

Comment: Use join to get the complete result.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for comment .. Any code ?

Comment: which type of code do you want?

Comment: @Rahul  the join code or how to do what you said in java code ?

Comment: show me the queries and table schema. I am talking about sql join query to fetch records from multiple database.

Comment: @Rahul i Updated My Question with my code